# Adding escape sequence for space in Snowflake PUT command

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowsql

I have been trying to load a file into Snowflake using PUT but I am getting an error due to space in the folder name.

```
PUT file://Y:/AMI Control/file.csv  @MS_FILE_LND
AUTO_COMPRESS=FALSE
```

I have tried using \ escape sequence and enclosing the entire path in quotes but it doesn't seem to be working.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This would work

For Linux/Mac:

```
PUT 'file:///AMI Control/file.csv'  @MS_FILE_LND AUTO_COMPRESS=FALSE
```

For Windows:

```
PUT 'file://Y:\AMI Control\file.csv'  @MS_FILE_LND AUTO_COMPRESS=FALSE
```

Answer (score 6):

The Windows version is incorrect.   The correct PUT statement is:

`PUT 'file://Y:/AMI Control/file.csv'  @MS_FILE_LND AUTO_COMPRESS=FALSE`

Snowflake documentation says:

> "The URI can be enclosed in single quotes, which allows special
> characters, including spaces, in directory and file names; however,
> the drive and path separator is a forward slash (/) for all supported
> operating systems (e.g. 'file://C:/temp/load data' for a path in
> Windows containing a directory named load data)."

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/put.html

Comment: The forward slashes / in your Windows example worked for me, FYI, thanks!